# Portability of path.Join for URL paths

Tags: go

We're using `path.Join` to construct the URL for a set of files:

```
urlPath := "/"
if isPrimaryLocale {
    urlPath = path.Join(urlPath, locale)
}
urlPath = path.Join(urlPath, itemName)
```

I'm curious as to the portability of this approach, since afaik a different path separator would be used on Windows (not a concern for us since we always deploy to Linux, but wondering for other applications).

Is `path.Join` safe to be used on paths intended for URLs? Is there an alternative approach that is URL specific?

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/path/#pkg-overview

Comment: I probably going to use https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#ResolveReference instead of path join

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `path.Join` is safe because **URLs are not platform-specific**, they *always* use `/` as a directory separator. If you need platform-specific file path handling, use [`filepath`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/) instead of `path`.

See also: Wikipedia's entry on [URIs/URLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) and [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) which defines them.